# react.js Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, setstate

Here is my `Profile` class :

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
state={email:'',userName:'',userID:''};
getData()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            this.setState({'userID':JSON.parse(this.responseText).userID});
            console.log(this.responseText);
          Profile.this.setState({userID:JSON.parse(this.responseText).userID});
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/user/1');
    request.send();
}
componentWillMount() {
    this.getData()
}
render() {
    return(
<div>
     {this.props.userID}
</div>
    );
}
}
 export default Profile;
```

It gives me error saying **Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined**.

Error in line :

`Profile.this.setState({userID:JSON.parse(this.responseText).userID});`

What's wrong here? How this can be resolved ?

Comment: Profile.this is undefined. use this.setState instead of Profile.this.setState

Comment: this.setState gives the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Profile.this`, `Profile` is a class, you'll have to keep a reference to the instance or use an arrow function instead of a normal function, the easiest way here will be to keep a reference to the component, here is an example:

```
getData()
{
    var that = this;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            that.setState({'userID':JSON.parse(this.responseText).userID});
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/user/1');
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: Here is my current code 
                `console.log(this.responseText);`
                `that.setState({userID:JSON.parse(this.responseText).userID});`
                `console.log(that.userID);`     

    Which gives me this : *Profile.js:41 {"userID":1,"phone":null,"firstName":null,"middleName":null,"lastName":null,"adminOf":null,"memberOf":null,"email":"admin@admin.com"}
Profile.js:43 undefined*

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad If you want to view the changes, it should be something like this: `that.setState({'userID':JSON.parse(this.responseText).userID}, () => console.log(that.state.userID))`

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad `userID` is added to `this.state` not directly to `this`. Also, `setState` doesn't change the state immediately (it's async), you'll have to wait or call `setState` with a function as the second parameter (a callback which is run after the state was set).

Comment: After these shouldn't it refresh the page and re-render everything ?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Yes, after you call `setState` the component's `render` function should be called.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad You've used `this.props.userID` instead of `this.state.userID` in the `render` function.

Comment: For best practices check my answer @MaifeeUlAsad

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of mistakes here is the correct way of doing this

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // You need to set the initial state inside the constructor
    this.state = { email: "", userName: "", userID: "" };
  }
  getData() {
    // use let instead of var
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // call request.open outside of the handler
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/user/1");
    // use an arrow function so that you will have access to the class this context
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
      // you must directly reference request, not this
      if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        const { userID } = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        // destruct instead of typing the entire thing
        // use the shorthand way of creating object with same name properties
        this.setState({ userID });
      }
    };
    // call request.send outside of the handler
    request.send();
  }
  // use componentDidMount , componentWillMount is deprecated
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  render() {
    // you should get the userID from the this.state not this.props
    return <div>{this.state.userID}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: _"You need to set the initial state inside the constructor"_ You don't **need** to, both  are valid ways to create a class property.

Comment: _"use let instead of var"_ `let` or `var` doesn't change anything here. Though you should use `const` to avoid accidentally reassigning `request`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

you have multiple this contexts that refer to different things.

```
getData = () => {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            this.setState({'userID':JSON.parse(request.responseText).userID});

            console.log(this.responseText);
            this.setState({userID:JSON.parse(request.responseText).userID});
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/user/1');
    request.send();
}
```